# Decoding URL-encoded GET parameters

Tags: php, api, url-encoding

While intercepting traffic of an app I got this GET APIs, but I don't know how to decode them so that they look like what they actually are.

> /api/v1/referral/createuser?phoneNumber=7018805137&deviceImeiId=lQAHMiAwBx%2B%2FchlgHKjWfA%3D%3D%0A&hardwareSerialNumber=bcZ%2Bb5VrI84UN%2FWXJj8hyQ%3D%3D%0A&macAddress=pDQheRx1nNFqOz%2Fw9Y9bI3I96uVKXjhkDXNhNgV%2FyGw%3D%0A&androidID=PQ9kdlHyznGdGKcl0QYh3hp4XeRUz0bBVMnABcxRsZ8%3D%0A&referralCode=7JMYUZ&lastEnabledTime=1481449847956&updateTime=1481449669855&installationTime=1481449669855

Comment: the variables LastEnabledTime, updateTime, installationTime are timestamps. phoneNumber looks like it's plaintext. What is the purpose of this, what are you trying?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the variables if this was sent to your server as a Get request like...

$_Get['phoneNumber'], $_GET['hardwareSerialNumber'] and so forth

If you are just asking for help to decode the string...

```
$urlstring = 'phoneNumber=7018805137&deviceImeiId=lQAHMiAwBx%2B%2FchlgHKjWfA%3D%3D%0A&hardwareSerialNumber=bcZ%2Bb5VrI84UN%2FWXJj8hyQ%3D%3D%0A&macAddress=pDQheRx1nNFqOz%2Fw9Y9bI3I96uVKXjhkDXNhNgV%2FyGw%3D%0A&androidID=PQ9kdlHyznGdGKcl0QYh3hp4XeRUz0bBVMnABcxRsZ8%3D%0A&referralCode=7JMYUZ&lastEnabledTime=1481449847956&updateTime=1481449669855&installationTime=1481449669855';

foreach (explode('&', $urlstring) as $chunk) {
    $param = explode("=", $chunk);

    if ($param) {
        printf("Value for parameter \"%s\" is \"%s\"<br/>\n", urldecode($param[0]), urldecode($param[1]));
    }
}
```

It will print the following

> Value for parameter "phoneNumber" is "7018805137"
>
> Value for parameter "deviceImeiId" is "lQAHMiAwBx+/chlgHKjWfA== "
>
> Value for parameter "hardwareSerialNumber" is
>   "bcZ+b5VrI84UN/WXJj8hyQ== "
>
> Value for parameter "macAddress" is
>   "pDQheRx1nNFqOz/w9Y9bI3I96uVKXjhkDXNhNgV/yGw= "
>
> Value for parameter "androidID" is
>   "PQ9kdlHyznGdGKcl0QYh3hp4XeRUz0bBVMnABcxRsZ8= "
>
> Value for parameter "referralCode" is "7JMYUZ"
>
> Value for parameter "lastEnabledTime" is "1481449847956"
>
> Value for parameter "updateTime" is "1481449669855"
>
> Value for parameter "installationTime" is "1481449669855"

Comment: I am not able to get you can you explain some more

Comment: @BobbyPal I think you need to be more precise with your questions or provide more information. Do you have a code which you have in hand that you can share so we can help you with it?

Comment: I just want to random androidid in above code can you explain how i can ?

Comment: if u just want help to get the values i have already updated the answer to parse the string.